# On characteristic function of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

I cant make sense of (4.2), putting $Z=1$ should only establish one point not the whole function right, hence I dont see how Thm 4.1 is "proved"? Second RHS is not even a funtion of $t$. Anyone have any idea what Im missing?

Comment: Substitute m and $\sigma$ (that do depend on t) in the rhs

Comment: @Ant the $\varphi_{Z}(1)$ still puzzles me, $Z$ is the scalar product right?

Comment: Scalar product of t and X, yes. What confuses you?

Comment: @Ant that we have the first equality

Comment: Well but $\varphi_X(t) = e^{iZ}= \varphi_Z(1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $m$ and $σ$ (that do depend on t) in the RHS.